# Jsoup on Android throws NoClassDefFoundError: java.applet.Applet

Tags: android, applet, jsoup, noclassdeffounderror

This problem has been resolved by circumvention, but should anyone want to have a go at figuring out the solution I'll leave it unanswered. For anyone looking for a quick fix: I made it work simply by replacing Jsoup with [jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html), which worked without any hiccups.

I've got a pretty weird problem, as described in the title. I'm doing some html scraping, which is working just fine on my computer, but as soon as I make it an Android apk, the library seems to break. I'm using Jsoup 1.7.1. This is example code which duplicates the error.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GetHtml updater = new GetHtml();
        updater.execute();
    }

    public class GetHtml extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            Document doc;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com").get();
                String header = doc.getElementsByTag("h1").get(0).text();
                return header;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String arg0){
            ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.listView1);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            adapter.add(arg0);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

This throws a bunch of errors, but the one that stands out is

```
01-16 19:30:47.793: E/AndroidRuntime(29082): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.applet.Applet
```

This is rather annoying, as I see a lot of projects using Jsoup just fine, and tutorials as well. Does anyone know what is causing this?

Oh, and just for clarity, I have the Jsoup-1.7.1.jar both linked as an external jar and copied into $PROJECT_ROOT/libs.

Comment: I had a similar problem while using Jsoup.parse(someHtmlString). I was getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.parser.Parser. I tried both Jsoup 1.8.1 and 1.8.3, but the error was still there.Surprisingly the error was happening only on Android API level 19 but not on Android API level 23.  As  circumvention i moved to "jericho"

Answer (score 0):

With targets of API 11 or higher, you are not allowed to access the network from the main UI thread.  If you do, you get a [NetworkOnMainThreadExeption](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html).  Check your logs for that exception, because you are accessing the network from your main UI thread.

You can fix it by putting your jsoup fetching and processing into an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: I am indeed targeting a later API, and I was not aware of this, so I am grateful, but putting the code in an AsyncTask did not fix the problem, I am still getting the same exception. I have updated my code example to use AsyncTask.

Comment: @BjornSnoen can you post more of the logcat to see where the error is steaming from?  Your code works fine for me after the AsyncTask change, so a deeper stack trace might point the way to go.

Comment: I'm sorry, I would do that, but I fixed my problem by replacing Jsoup with jericho. I'm still befuddled as to why Jsoup wanted the Applet class, but I lack the resolve to spend another five hours trying to figure it out tonight. Still, I appreciate your help.